# Could I have an explanation of a few lines in the following code?

Tags: c++

I would like to understand how the following code works. It can basically be used to sort of "Debug" C++ containers, but I'm having some trouble understanding lines 3, 4, 12 and 13 and what they do. It would be great if I could receive a brief explanation. Thanks.

```
template <typename T> class range { public: T begin, end; };
template <typename T> range <T> make_range (const T& b, const T& e) { return range <T> {b, e}; }
template <typename T> auto dec (T* x) -> decltype(std::cerr << *x, 0); // 3
template <typename T> char dec (...);  // 4
class view {
private:
    std::ostream& stream;
public:
     view (std::ostream&);
    ~view ();
#ifdef Z_LOCAL
    template <typename T> typename std::enable_if <sizeof dec <T> (0) != 1, view&>::type operator << (const T&);  // 12
    template <typename T> typename std::enable_if <sizeof dec <T> (0) == 1, view&>::type operator << (const T&);  // 13
    template <typename T> view& operator << (const range <T>&);
    template <typename A, typename B> view& operator << (const std::pair <A, B>&);
#else
    template <typename T> view& operator << (const T&);
#endif
};

view::view (std::ostream& os = std::cerr) : stream (os) { }

view::~view () { stream << std::endl; }

#ifdef Z_LOCAL
template <typename T> typename std::enable_if <sizeof dec <T> (0) != 1, view&>::type view::operator << (const T& t)
{ stream << std::boolalpha << t; return *this; }

template <typename T> typename std::enable_if <sizeof dec <T> (0) == 1, view&>::type view::operator << (const T& t)
{ return *this << make_range(begin(t), end(t)); }

template <typename T> view& view::operator << (const range <T>& r)
{ stream << "["; for (auto i = r.begin, j = i; i != r.end; ++i) *this << *i << (++j == r.end ? "]" : ", "); return *this; }

template <typename A, typename B> view& view::operator << (const std::pair <A, B>& p)
{ stream << '(' << p.first << ", " << p.second << ')'; return *this; }
#else
template <typename T> view& view::operator << (const T&)
{ return *this; }
#endif

#define print(x) " [" << #x << ": " << x << "] "
view debug (std::cerr);
```

Comment: We can't see what lines 3, 4, 12 and 13 are. Add comments next to those lines.

Comment: Can you add some context? It would help to know where you took this from

Comment: Looks to me that `dec` is a function which is overloaded to return a `char` or an `int`. It returns an `int` in the case when `T` can be output to `cerr`. So it's used to distinguish types which can or can't be printed. Clever stuff, never seen this technique before. The overall technique being used here is SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error), perhaps you could google that.

Comment: @cigien I'm sorry. I didn't realise the line numbers do not get displayed here like in an editor. Quimby seems to have edited my post and fixed that problem.

Comment: @JoãoAreias The original code was copied from [here](https://codeforces.com/submissions/Errichto). It was not very readable to me and so I edited it a tad bit to make it look neat, and it's the one I've posted.

Comment: @john Thanks. I think that clears it up for me then, if that's what it is. Cool stuff indeed.

Comment: Renaming `dec` into `is_streamable_impl` would have been clearer, and as code already use C++11 (use `std::enable_if`), return type could be `std::true_type`/`std::false_type`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following declarations are using a technique that relies on SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error):

```
// #3 : works only if  (std::cerr << *x) works
template <typename T> auto dec (T* x) -> decltype(std::cerr << *x, 0);

// #4 : works for everything, but only if #3 fails
template <typename T> char dec (...);
```

Consider some type `T` such as `double`. Then the following code, where `x` is a `double*`:

```
std::cerr << *x;
```

would compile just fine, which means that this code:

```
decltype(std::cerr << *x, 0);
```

is well formed, and evaluates to `int`. The compiler will then pick `#3` when `T` is a type that can be used like this.

On the other hand, if `T` is something like a `vector<double>`, then the `decltype` is not well formed (since you can't stream a `vector` to `cerr`), and so the compiler has no choice but to pick `#4`.

---

The above declarations are simply helpers that are used in `#12` and `#13`. If `T` is a type that works for `#3`, then `dec` has a return type of `int`, and the following overload is matched:

```
// #12
template <typename T> typename std::enable_if <sizeof dec <T> (0) != 1, view&>::type operator << (const T&);
```

because `sizeof dec <T>` would not be 1.

If `T` works for `#4` (because it didn't work for `#3`), then `dec` has a return type of `int`, and the following overload `#13` is matched:

```
// #13
template <typename T> typename std::enable_if <sizeof dec <T> (0) == 1, view&>::type operator << (const T&);
```

because `sizeof dec <T>` would be exactly 1 (the size of a `char`).

---

Note that the real difference is how `#12` and `#13` are *defined*. If you see the definitions, they handle the cases where `T` is streamable or not appropriately.