# Replication of same behaviour without using decltype

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

The code below comes in handy for fast debugging. It can pretty print containers like vectors from the STL while also being able to provide the printing-ness property for fundamental and streamable types using SFINAE techniques.

I would like to replicate the same behaviour without the use of `decltype`. Any other neat techniques of replicating this behaviour will be very helpful implementation-wise for a few projects I have in mind. The current thread may also be considered as a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063310/could-i-have-an-explanation-of-a-few-lines-in-the-following-code) thread (also by me). I managed to get a neat working implementation with `concepts` in C++20 (GCC 10.2.0) without the use of `decltype` but I would like to be able to do so in C++17 (GCC 9.2.0) and lower (obviously, without concepts, and decltype as mentioned).

```cpp
namespace debugging {
    template <typename T>
    class range {
      public:
        T begin, end;
    };

    template <typename T>
    auto make_range (const T& b, const T& e) -> range <T> {
        return {b, e};
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto is_streamable_object (T *x) -> decltype(std::cerr << *x, std::true_type());

    template <typename T>
    auto is_streamable_object (...)  -> decltype(std::false_type());

    class view {
      private:
        std::ostream& stream;
      public:
        view (std::ostream& os = std::cerr) : stream (os)
        { };

        ~view ()
        { stream << std::endl; };

  #ifdef LOST_IN_SPACE
        template <typename T>
        std::enable_if_t <std::is_same <decltype(is_streamable_object <T> (nullptr)), std::true_type>::value, view&>
        operator << (const T& t) {
            stream << std::boolalpha << t; return *this;
        }

        template <typename T>
        std::enable_if_t <std::is_same <decltype(is_streamable_object <T> (nullptr)), std::false_type>::value, view&>
        operator << (const T& t) {
            return *this << make_range(begin(t), end(t));
        }

        template <typename T>
        view& operator << (const range <T>& r) {
            stream << "[";
            for (auto i = r.begin, j = i; i != r.end; ++i)
                *this << *i << (++j == r.end ? "]" : ", ");
            return *this;
        }

        template <typename A, typename B>
        view& operator << (const std::pair <A, B>& p) {
            stream << '(' << p.first << ", " << p.second << ')';
            return *this;
        }
  #else
        template <typename T> view& operator << (const T&)
        { return *this; }
  #endif
    };
} // namespace debugging
```

Test code in case you'd like to try it quickly yourself:

```cpp
#define print(x) " [" << #x << ": " << x << "] "

using view = debugging::view;
view debug (std::cerr);

auto test () -> void {
    std::vector <int> v {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::map <int, int> m {{1,2}, {3,4}};
    debug << print(v) print(m) << "\nHello World";
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want an alternative to `decltype` here? Nothing wrong with just being curious, but I'm wondering if you have a specific reason.

Comment: @cigien Just curious. I don't like seeing decltype in code I write :p

Comment: Haha, ok. I must say, you're unlikely to like what the alternative looks like though. Achieving `decltype` semantics without using that keyword will *probably* end up being syntactically more unpleasant :p

Comment: @cigien Oh! Well, it wouldn't hurt knowing other techniques, hehe. If it's unpleasant, like you mention, it'll be a good learning experience (and it's up to me to decide that too :)). I like decltype for what it does but I find it rather confusing when I'm reading other people's code and so I try not to use it when working on my small projects (unless if I don't have alternatives that I know of).

Comment: `decltype` was added to the language for a reason. And no, learning pre-`decltype` SFINAE techniques will not benefit you in the slightest. It would be better to spend time getting used to seeing `decltype`, particularly in pre-C++20 SFINAE.

Comment: @NicolBolas Your comment makes sense. However, it is unrelated to my original question statement:` "I would like to replicate the same behaviour without the use of decltype."` If there are ways, I would like to know about them, irrespective of the fact that they're going to be helpful to me or not. If there aren't, then okay, this question can be closed. I feel that your comment is irrelevant here and was only said as a reply to `Just curious. I don't like seeing decltype in code I write :p` and my other comment, but the comments must not be confused/mixed with the original question.

Comment: This seems to be a Code Review question in disguise: the code works, but you want it to be nicer.  Asking about a particular candidate means of doing so (avoiding `decltype`) makes it a factual question that we can answer here, but also makes it of almost purely academic interest absent some substantive reason for choosing that approach.  (In particular, you’d mind “seeing decltype in code” much less if it were done with the (imperfect) elegance that is possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here's an implementation using `sizeof`:

```
template<class T, class = std::false_type>
struct is_streamable_object : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_streamable_object<T,
    std::bool_constant<sizeof(std::cerr << std::declval<T>()) == 0>> : std::true_type {};
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/PGv65e).

Other keywords you could use include `alignof`, `noexcept`, `typeid`, and `explicit` (the last since C++20).

Essentially, you want to perform expression SFINAE, which requires constructing an expression that is not to be evaluated. The [operators that allow constructing unevaluated expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Unevaluated_expressions) are those mentioned above plus `decltype` (which you do not want to use) and `requires` (C++20).

Comment: This is perfect! I find this sort of stuff way cleaner than using decltype 4 times to simply evaluate whether something is streamable or not. Thank you for the extra details too!

Comment: You don't need to use decltype 4 times - once will suffice (with std::void_t). Example: https://godbolt.org/z/ErT8eb

Comment: ecatmur You might have figured out yourself that I'm not very experienced with this :) In my original code, I used 4 decltype's and it looked very complicated to me for achieving something simple, and so I came here. Thank you again for the example!